# named or named as

Tags: grammaticality, usage, as

May I know which of the following sentences is grammatical?

> 1. This method named ABC is used to calculate the temperature of these categories of objects.
> 2. This method named **as** ABC is used to calculate the temperature of these categories of objects.
> 3. This method, named ABC, is used to calculate the temperature of these categories of objects.
> 4. This method, named **as** ABC, is used to calculate the temperature of these categories of objects.

In sentences 3 and 4, I added commas.

In sentences 2 and 4, I inserted the word *as*.

Comment: You're varying two things: 1. whether you put the phrase in commas; and 2. whether you insert the word "as".  So really, there are four possibilities here: `+commas +as`, `+commas -as`, `-commas +as`, `-commas -as`.

Comment: I'm going to insert the other two possibilities into your question.  If you feel that was a mistake, please feel free to roll the change back :-)

Comment: Named alone is correct as @chrylis (below) said. No matter how well we punctuate it.

Answer (score 9):

Using **as** isn't strictly ungrammatical, but it's not standard usage in this sort of sentence; just use **named ABC**.

You should use the commas. In this sentence, **named ABC** is what's called *non-restrictive*: It doesn't serve to limit the identification of **method**, whose identity is already clear. Non-restrictive phrases, like this one, are set off in commas; you could strike out everything between the commas, and the sentence would still be clear. *Restrictive* phrases are necessary to properly identify the item being described and are not set off in commas.

**Examples**

> This method, named ABC, is used to calculate the temperature of these categories of objects.

The demonstrative adjective **This** clearly identifies which **method** you're talking about, so **named ABC** is extra information that's not required for the sentence to make sense.

> The method named ABC is used to calculate the temperature of these categories of objects.

Unless *which* **method** is clear from the context, you need **named ABC** so the reader can tell which method you're talking about, so the phrase is restrictive; no commas.

Comment: Nice answer....

Comment: @Sweet72 Not unless I get 5 more upvotes. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "named as XYZ" means something quite different; it means the person has been identified by name as someone who is XYZ. For example:

> My brother is named as a beneficiary in my will.

If you want to say that someone's name is XYZ, just use "named XYZ".

> My brother is named Will.